# How to efficiently pop all elements with the smallest key in heapq?

Tags: python, priority-queue, heapq

I am working on a simulation experiment and trying to make my code as efficient as possible. In one part, I have a min heap priority queue that I have implemented using `heapq` module.

Throughout the simulation, I have to pop all elements with the smallest key. The straightforward approach to do this would be:

```
    elements = []
    k1, v1 = heapq.heappop(heap)
    elements.append((k1,v1))
    k2, v2 = heap[0] #looks at the smallest item without popping
    while(k1 == k2):
         k1, v1 = heapq.heappop(heap)
         elements.append((k1,v1))
         k2, v2 = heap[0]
    return elements
```

Answer (score 1):

The general technique you show is the most efficient as well as being straightforward. But you're doing extra assignments that aren't really necessary. Below is a minor optimization.

```
elements = []
k1, v1 = heapq.heappop(heap)
elements.append((k1,v1))
while(k1 == heap[0]):
     k2, v2 = heapq.heappop(heap)
     elements.append((k2,v2))
return elements
```

To be on the safe side, you probably should add checks to make sure your heap isn't empty. Checking `heap[0]` when there are no items in the heap would be a bad thing, as would calling `heapq.heappop` if the heap is empty.

Comment: `while k1 == heap[0][0]:` in this case, as each element in `heap` is a `(k, v)` tuple.
And simply adding `while heap and k1 == heap[0][0]:` will ensure that you never try to do anything to an empty heap.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest a change of structure from a heap of `(k, v)` to a heap of `k` and a dictionary of `{k:[v]}`. This would turn your code into:

```
k = heap[0]
return [(k,v) for v in hash[k]]
```

With:

```
hash = defaultdict(list)
heap = []
```

`heappush(heap, (k, v))` would become:

```
heappush(heap, k)
hash[k].append(v)
```

`heappop(heap)` would become:

```
k = heappop(heap)
v = hash[k].pop()
```

Comment: How is that more efficient? He's doing the same amount of work. Your code just complicates it by adding another data structure.